# Add custom method to abstract class that implements another repository Interface to have both generic methods and custom methods in one place

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Repository that extends JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person , String> {
    @Query(...)
    List<Something> findSomethingBySomething();
    List<Person> findPersonByNameAndAge(String name, int age);
}
```

So I want a CustomRepository such as that repository has PersonRepository (inherited) methods along side custom methods that has criteria builder query.

Something like this.

```
@Repository
public abstract class PersonRepositoryCustom implements PersonRepository {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public void customMethod() {
        // uses criteria builder, criteria query to create custom query using 
    }
}
```

In service, I want to use only that PersonRepositoryCustom so that I can get all the methods from PersonRepository as well as methods from PersonRepositoryCustom;

Something like this

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepositoryCustom personRepository;

// I want to access all methods like
    public void method() {
        personRepository.save();
        personRepository.findPersonByNameAndAge("name", 20);
        personRepository.findSomethingBySomething();
        personRepository.customMethod();
        personRepository.findById();
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Can I do that? Or How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way:

```java
interface CustomPersonRepository {
  void customMethod();
}

@Repository
class CustomPersonRepositoryImpl implements CustomPersonRepository { /* implementation */}

public interface PersonRepository 
      extends JpaRepository<Person , String>, CustomPersonRepository {
    ...
}
```

Note that `PersonRepository` extends `CustomPersonRepository`.

Now you can inject `PersonRepository` and it will have the implementations from `CustomPersonRepositoryImpl`